# Error with zend installation on win 7

Tags: zend-framework, installation

I am trying to install **ZEND FRAMEWORK** on my localhost but failing miserable. I am following the below mentioned steps but don't know where am I going wrong. Please help me with the same.

Steps are as follows that I followed:

1. Downloaded the ZEND Framework full package version 1.11.7 which is about 25 Mb in a zipped version and then unzipped it to a folder called ZendFrameWork.
2. Copied the ZendFramework folder inside my c:\xampp\php\
3. changed the "include_path = '.;\xampp\php\PEAR;\.;C:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\library' "  in the php.ini file.
4. Then restarted the apache server.

EDIT :: I have successfully managed to get the zf command to run without any errors. but now, all it does is, after i enter "zf create myproject" it just gets stuck with the cursor blinking on the next line. And if i press CTRL+C, i get the message : Terminate batch job ? (Y/N)

5. Then set the environment variable for zf.bat file as " C:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\bin "
6. But when I try to execute the " zf create sampleProjName " from command line it does nothing, so then I used Windows Powershell and it gives the error which I have attached below.

Waiting for your response. 
Thanks in advance.

[image: Error On Executing the zf command after setting it as environment variable]

Comment: Are you sure zf.bat is in your path? Drop into a command shell and type `path` and check if you indeed have it in the path.

Comment: i removed the old full installation and replaced it with minimal installation and now its giving me the following error.
Any leads on this ??
http://twitpic.com/58kzfk/full

Comment: Have you considered reading and interpreting the error message? Perhaps then, you could try putting the folder where php.exe lives into the path as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try using normal cmd - not powershell. Works fine for me.

Comment: @thomas I tried that as well but it doesnt do anything !!
For your reference : http://twitpic.com/58kc0y/full

Comment: i removed the old full installation and replaced it with minimal installation and now its giving me the following error.
Any leads on this ??
http://twitpic.com/58kzfk/full

Comment: yes, much better - you need to have php.exe in your PATH variable

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your response.
I successfully installed Zend Framework.

I removed the full installation and replaced it with minimal installation and also I did not have php.exe set as an environment variable, so i did that too and also in the php.ini file i needed to write the zend library first before the pear one.

And this was it, TA-DA, it worked.

:)